# How to force refresh of changed cells with Qt Custom TableModel (deriving from QAbstractTableModel) ?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm new to Qt. I'm trying to implement a custom table model :

I have a class DataSource which contains all my data and fires events (traditional ones, not Qt signa/slots) when rows changed, or when only some values changed in one row. Here is a simplified version:

```
class DataSource{
  public:
  int size();
  int nbColumns();
  const std::string& data(int row, int col);
  bool hasChanges();
};
```

I implement a TableModel as a wraper of my datasource:

```
class MyTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
  public:

  int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const {
      return datasource->size();
  }

  int columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const {
    return datasource->nbColumns();
  }

  QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const {
    return QVariant(datasource.data(index.row(), index.column());
  }
};
```

I refresh my table on a timer (too many updates in my app):

```
void timerRefresh(){
  if(datasource->hasChanges()){
    ui->tableView->repaint();
    ui->tableView->update();
  }
}
```

This doesn't work (I was expecting that the view would query the model on repaint, but maybe I should invoke another method?)

So I've added this just before the call to repaint:

```
tableModel->update();
```

which is defined as follows:

```
void MyTableModel::update()
{
  beginResetModel();
  endResetModel();
  //doesn't work: emit dataChanged(createIndex(0,0), createIndex(DataSource->size(), DataSource->nbColumns()));
}
```

It works, but if only one cell is changed, I guess there should be something more efficient than resetting the whole model ? And why the emit DataChanged does not work?
The documentation is not clear on which function is called by the Qt framework and which function I should call explicitly...

EDIT: Thanks to the comment below, I understood how it works. I do not need to call anything on the QTableView itself, I just update my model and call
            beginResetModel();
            ...
            endResetModel();

or simply when only cells changed:
            emit dataChanged(...);

Comment: Why do you want to manually update the view?

Comment: @scopchanov Well It's not that I want it, if you know how I can get the view repaint as long as my model is updated, then that's even better... But it's not clear then which method I should call to get it working..

Comment: The idea behind the model/view is that the view should be automatically updated once the data in the model changes. Hence, there is no need to do that manually. In order to be able to help you further, please prepare a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the issue (including your custom model).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Qt versions changes all the time. Changing from one version to the other is trivial. Planning your project is very important. Qt Widgets that you choose for your user interface (ui) are import. Qt Widgets transmits signals, you can connect to those signals by using slots. Depending on what you want to do with your project. When implementing some of the functions, it is important to call the appropriate functions so that all connected views are aware of any changes. QAbstractTableModel may be useful for developers who want to implement their own table models or custom delegates. There is a theory behind the MVC (Model, View and Controller). Implementing MVC will solve the problem. There are many strategies you can use to implement it. The starting point is planning.
You can use the class DataSource and class MyTableModel as Models. What is missing is the definition of the Views and Controllers.   Your “#include”s are also importent in Qt. QAbstractTableModel provides the standard MV API to access data. We can use QtableView  to view data using different views. The basic functions that must be implemented are: rowCount(), columnCount(), data(), headerData(). For TableModel to be editable, it has to provide implementations insertRows(), removeRows(), setData() and flags() functions.

---

1. **Demo Custom Table.**

---

[image]

---

2. **main.cpp**

---

```
//
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
Widget w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
//
```

---

3. **widget.h**

---

```
//
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QListView>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QDateEdit>
#include <QString>
//namespace Ui {
//class Widget;
//}
class MyTableModel;
class Widget : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
//explicit Widget(QObject t, QWidget *parent = 0);
Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
~Widget();
public slots:
void updateView();
private:
//Ui::Widget *ui;
QTableView *tableView;
MyTableModel *tableModel;
QLineEdit *ledMessage;
QLabel *lblMessage;
QTextBrowser *logs;
QDateEdit *dateEdit;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
//
```

---

4. **widget.cpp**

---

```
//
#include <QtGui>
#include "mytablemodel.h"
#include "widget.h"
//#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QGridLayout>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent)/*,
ui(new Ui::Widget*)*/
{
//ui->setupUi(this);
tableModel = new MyTableModel(this);
tableView = new QTableView;
tableView->setModel(tableModel);
lblMessage = new QLabel(tr("&Message:"));
ledMessage = new QLineEdit;
lblMessage->setBuddy(ledMessage);
dateEdit = new QDateEdit(QDate::currentDate());
logs = new QTextBrowser;
logs->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred));

QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
layout->addWidget(lblMessage, 0, 0);
layout->addWidget(ledMessage, 0, 1);
layout->addWidget(dateEdit, 0, 2);
layout->addWidget(tableView, 1, 0, 1, 2);
layout->addWidget(logs, 2, 0, 1, 2);

setLayout(layout);
setWindowTitle(tr("Demo Custom Table."));
//connect(ledMessage, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)),
//             tableModel, SLOT(newMessage(const QString &)));
//connect(tableModel, SIGNAL(updateMode()),
//             this, SLOT(updateView()));
connect(ledMessage, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this, SLOT(updateView()));
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
//delete ui;
}

void Widget::updateView()
{
QModelIndex p = tableView->currentIndex();
tableModel->update(p,ledMessage->text(), dateEdit->text());
logs->append(tr("%1 : ").arg(p.row()));
logs->append(ledMessage->text());
}
//
```

---

5. **mytablemodel.h**

---

```
//
#ifndef MYTABLEMODEL_H
#define MYTABLEMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QLabel>
//#include <QDateEdit>
#include <QDateTime>
#include "datasource.h"

class MyTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
//explicit MyTableModel(QObject t, QObject t2,QObject *parent = 0);
MyTableModel(QObject *parent = 0);
MyTableModel(QList< QPair<QString,QString> > t, QObject *parent = 0);
int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
QVariant headerData(int part, Qt::Orientation orient, int role) const;
void update(const QModelIndex &parent,const QString &mes, const QString &date);
bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role=Qt::EditRole);
Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;
bool insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index=QModelIndex());
bool removeRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index=QModelIndex());

signals:
void updateMod();

public slots:
void newMessage(const QString &mes);

protected:
void update(const QModelIndex &parent);

private:
DataSource *datasource;
QPair<QString,QString> message;
QList< QPair<QString,QString> > messageList;
QList<QString> dList;
int listSize;
int col;
QLabel *lblNumber;
QDateTime *dTime;
//QDateEdit *dateEdit;
};

#endif // MYTABLEMODEL_H
//
```

---

6. **mytablemodel.cpp**

---

```
//    
#include "mytablemodel.h"
#include <QApplication>

MyTableModel::MyTableModel(QObject *parent) :
QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
datasource = new DataSource();
lblNumber = new QLabel;
dTime = new QDateTime();
//dateEdit = new QDateEdit(QDate::currentDate());
col = datasource->nbColumns();
int l = datasource->size();
for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)
{
    message.first = datasource->data(i,0);
    message.second = datasource->data(i,1);
    messageList.append(message);
    dList.append(dTime->currentDateTime().toString());
}
listSize = messageList.size();

}

MyTableModel::MyTableModel(QList< QPair<QString,QString> > t, QObject *parent) :
QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
messageList = t;
datasource = new DataSource();
listSize = t.length();
col = datasource->nbColumns();
}

void MyTableModel::update(const QModelIndex &,const QString &mes, const QString &d)
{
int first = messageList.count();
int last = first + 1;
first = last;
lblNumber->setText(tr("%1").arg(first));
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(),first,last);
message.first = lblNumber->text();
message.second = mes;
messageList.append(message);
dList.append(d);
listSize++;
endInsertRows();
datasource->hasChanges();
}

int MyTableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &p) const
{
Q_UNUSED(p);
return listSize;
}

int MyTableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &p) const
{
Q_UNUSED(p);
return col;
}

QVariant MyTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
int c = 0;
if (!index.isValid())
{
   return QVariant();
}
if(index.row() < 0)
{
   return QVariant();
}
if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
{
    c = index.column();
    if(c == 0)
    {
       return messageList.at(index.row()).first;
    }
    else if (c == 1)
    {
       return messageList.at(index.row()).second;
    }

    return dList.at(index.row());
}

return QVariant();
}

void MyTableModel::update(const QModelIndex &p)
{
Q_UNUSED(p);
emit updateMod();
}

void MyTableModel::newMessage(const QString &mes)
{
listSize++;
message.first = lblNumber->text();
message.second = mes;
messageList.append(message);
dList.append(dTime->currentDateTime().toString());
}

bool MyTableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
QString d = dTime->currentDateTime().toString();
if (index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole)
{
    int row = index.row();

    message = messageList.value(row);
    if (index.column() == 0)
    message.first = value.toString();
    else if (index.column() == 1)
    message.second = value.toString();
    else
    return false;

    messageList.replace(row, message);
    dList.replace(row,d);
    emit(dataChanged(index, index));

     return true;
 }

 return false;
}

bool MyTableModel::insertRows(int post, int rows, const QModelIndex &p)
{
 Q_UNUSED(p);
 beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), post, post+rows-1);
 for (int row=0; row < rows; row++)
 {
     message.first = " ";
     message.second = " ";
     messageList.insert(post, message);
     dList.insert(post, " ");
 }
 endInsertRows();
 return true;
}

bool MyTableModel::removeRows(int post, int rows, const QModelIndex &p)
{
 Q_UNUSED(p);
 beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), post, post+rows-1);
 for (int row=0; row < rows; ++row)
 {
     messageList.removeAt(post);
     dList.removeAt(post);
 }
 endRemoveRows();
 return true;
}

Qt::ItemFlags MyTableModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
 if (!index.isValid())
     return Qt::ItemIsEnabled;

 return QAbstractTableModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}

QVariant MyTableModel::headerData(int part, Qt::Orientation orient, int role) const
{
 if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
     return QVariant();

 if (orient == Qt::Horizontal)
 {
     switch (part)
     {
         case 0:
             return tr("Number");

         case 1:
             return tr("Message");

         case 2:
             return tr("Date");

         default:
             return QVariant();
     }
 }
 return QVariant();
}
//
```

---

7. **datasource.h**

---

```
//
#include <QString>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QList>
#include <QPair>

class DataSource
{
public:
DataSource();
int size();
int nbColumns();
const QString& data(int row, int col);
bool hasChanges();

private:
int beginRow;
int columns;
QPair<QString,QString> message;
QList< QPair<QString,QString> > messages;
};

#endif // DATASOURCE_H
//
```

---

8. **datasource.cpp**

---

```
//
#include "datasource.h"

DataSource::DataSource()
{
beginRow = 1;
columns = 3;
message.first = "One";
message.second = "Testing123";
messages.push_back(message);
message.first = "Two";
message.second = "QObject";
messages.push_back(message);
message.first = "Three";
message.second = "QWidget";
messages.push_back(message);
}

int DataSource::size()
{
return messages.length();
}

int DataSource::nbColumns()
{
return columns;
}

const QString& DataSource::data(int r, int c)
{
int l = messages.length();
if(r < l)
{
    message = messages.at(r);
    if (c == 0)
    {
        return message.first;
    }
    else if (c == 1)
    {
       return message.second;
    }
}
return "Testing123";
}


bool DataSource::hasChanges()
{
beginRow++;
return true;
}
//
```

---

9. **customtab.pro**

---

```
//
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-09-10T15:39:01
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = customtab
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    widget.cpp \
datasource.cpp \
mytablemodel.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h \
datasource.h \
mytablemodel.h

#//FORMS    += widget.ui
//
```

---

10. **ENJOY.**

---

If you are new to Qt. Qt uses C++. It implements the GUI. Most C++ applications uses console applications. Qt uses design patterns and frameworks. Enjoy!

---

Comment: Although I haven't read in detail your long reply (I already found a solution), I accept it as an answer as this can be useful to others.

Comment: @SoyonsPrecis  This isn't a very good answer though -- it's full of irrelevant information about Qt, rather than pinpointing what was the problem with your code